# How can I allow my partner to find my device?

Tags: applications, lost-phone

When I lose my device (or think I did) I would like my partner to be able to locate it. However, I cannot find any such setting in the "Find my Device" app.

Is there maybe an alternative application that allows this?

Comment: [Google: Be ready to find a lost Android device](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a workaround, but I use the Automate app to turn the ringer volume up to maximum when my phone receives an SMS with a specific text from my partner's phone. Then she can ring my phone and it's easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

you must add the account of your partner on the devices and then open Find my Device app and login whit that account on the app and give some permissions, sorry i don't comment  instead of answer because it is not complete the answer but i don't have that privilege jet  ! :P I hope it helps  !